# googleanalytics.js not loading in ie 11

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using google analytics module for a drupal 7 multisite, and it works perfect in all browsers but in ie 11 where surprisingly the googleanalytics.js script is no loading.

any help?

thanks.

Comment: Why is not loading? Script not found? JavaScript error?

Comment: i just can't see it exploring the code neither with Dom Explorer nor with code source, and it's there when i open it with chrome, firefox or safari... and i've tried two sites with the same result.

Comment: I'm (fortunately) not used to IE 11, but I think it includes some sort of JavaScript console like Firebug. There you may see if there's any JS error or load problem, this will help to track down the problem.

Comment: no, i don't see any error on javascipt console.